# How to deal with "What is this effect called and where can I find a tutorial?"

Tags: discussion

There seem to be many questions in this form, which I think tend to indicate that the questioner hasn't found a canned tutorial within a few seconds of trying Google, and wants further research done for them.

It particularly annoys me that they ask 'where to find how to' rather than 'how to'.

But while I think they are particularly lazy questions, I think that they get reasonable answers, with suggestions on how to achieve the effect, rather than pointers to tutorials as actually requested.

So, how to deal with them?

Answer (score 11):

I tend to think the best way is to ruthlessly edit the question until it forms an model for the answers actually supplied.

Thus

> What is this effect called and where can I find a tutorial?

might become

> How to achieve a realistic engraved-marble text effect?

This ensures that good answers get seen, and makes the question findable in a search, which in turn makes it easier to close/merge new questions which address the same problem.

Comment: I like this solution. It's elegant and not terribly time-consuming.

Comment: Good point. I also think it would be helpful to vote to close duplicates WITHOUT supplying answers. It's too easy to get some good answers spread across 3 or 4 very similar questions.

Comment: @skaught I think I remember seeing somewhere, ages ago, that it's possible for moderators to merge questions - so say you have 4 questions that are duplicates, 2 of them each have a good answer each that aren't the same, you can delete 3 of the questions and put both good answers on the remaining question. Hopefully a moderator can clarify this in including who's able to do this, how, etc.

Comment: How DO I create a realistic engraved-marble effect?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Start with some marble and a chisel.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the e100 in general (specific cases it may be appropriate) because that could mean that we are editing in content, changing the nature of the question itself.

---

Instead, I suggest we categorize questions differently:

There are two types of classification: *style identification* and *how to*.

If someone doesn't know what the style is, they cannot find how to create such an effect, thus they use a question to find that out what the style is in order to look up more about it. Also note we have some [requirements for them](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2931/23061) as well.

How to's, on the other hand, seek for help with implementation creating a particular effect. We have [requirements for them](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/699/23061), but they are of a different nature than simply identifying a style. They involve steps of how to attain the desired effect.

So, questions like "What is this effect called and where can I find a tutorial?" are too broad and should be scoped to fit either one or other of the above categories, whichever is more applicable.

In any case, questions just asking for pointing to a tutorial should be closed or edited - we want to keep the answers of how to's on our site :)