# Is is OK to ask questions on how to use font editors?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Everything is inside the title.
So is it OK to ask technical support questions about font editor software ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Font Design is on topic here which means the tools used to do it are also on-topic. Be aware with all software specific questions we have implemented a policy of [What have you tried?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/699/request-new-close-reason-what-have-you-tried).

If someone comes in and asks "How do I make this E in Adobe Font Lab" then it would get closed under that policy.

If they show instead ask, "How can I fix this curve on my E that isn't aligning properly", and indicate let's say a particular curve that doesn't seem right to them using a screenshot and asks about ways to fix it, then it would be on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I personally do not have a problem with this and I also would likely upvote the question in regards to developing fonts.  That said it might depend on how you word the contents of the question and if some would consider it as technical support.

I know as a community some have expressed they are burned out on Adobe software but some of the questions I see that get answered or upvoted that are technical appear to be better written and show effort.

You could always give it a shot, and we can encourage an edit or some could help edit to make it better, but I do appreciate you actually coming to meta and asking.

Comment: I saw many typesetting questions though on-topic are poorly received, because they involve considerations which look opinion based, whereas they involve fact with studies. The purpose is to find more off-topic content on Graphics Design in order to make [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88060) different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that **well written** questions on just about anything related to Graphic Design are accepted here. That would largely include typography questions.

The primary issue with questions as they relate to software, including font software is the *type of question* it may be. Asking something which would take a higher-level understanding of the application is often answered. Asking something which the help files would answer is generally down voted and/or placed on hold due to lack of effort primarily.

There has been thread after thread after thread here on meta about what may or may not be technical software support. If your questions skirt that, then there's a higher probability they won't be accepted well by the community.

I think asking veiled questions such as this is a bit of bait-and-switch. Will this sight automatically close anything related to FontLab, Fontographer, BirdFont, Glyphs? **Heck no**. In fact we have questions already related to those software packages. Do we have questions as they relate to type usage? **Yes we do**. But again, a bad question is just a bad question regardless of the software being used or intent of the question.

If you are merely searching for things which would be seen as off-topic here, but on topic at a typography stack, you should ask that question. not a bunch of loosely worded, hard to define, tangent questions that are open to interpretation.

Comment: +1 to last paragraph