# What are the requirements for style identification questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic-definition, style-identification

I would like help identifying a design style. How should I construct my question to fit within this site's format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to promote high-quality style-identification questions, we ask that you follow a specific format. If your question has been placed on hold, please edit it to meet the following criteria:

#### ✔ DO: Use a descriptive title

As we don’t wish to have hundreds of questions titled “What style is this?”, we ask that you be as descriptive as possible in your title. Here are some examples on how it should be worded:

- What style of font is used for ACME Inc.’s logo?
- What style is the illustration on this event poster?
- What style of design does Example.com use for their navigation menu?

This helps keep the question useful to others and improves searchability.

#### ✔ DO: Add an image or images

We’re not psychic, we need to see what you are talking about! You can use the built-in image uploader to include images of the style you are interested in. Uploading more than one image may be a good idea, but don’t go overboard. As long as the style you are interested in is distinct enough then you shouldn’t need more than a few images – if you do, what you are looking at probably isn’t distinct enough to be a considered a style.

#### ✔ DO: Describe it in your own words

Many images combine more than one style or technique.
If you just ask “What’s the style used in this image?”, we have to guess what you are referring to.
Therefore try to describe the aspect of the image(s) you are interested in.
This in particular applies if you only have one example image.

#### ✔ DO: Tell us where it is from

Sometimes the origin of the images you post can help provide clues to identify it. As much relevant information as possible will go a long way. Include a link if it’s from a digital source, such as a website or PDF.

#### ✔ DO: Tell us what you’ve already attempted

A simple search on your favoured search engine will often get you what you want. You can also use reverse image searches to find the source of your image.

If none of those give you successful results, let us know which ones you have tried so that we’re not re-tracing steps you may have already taken.

#### ✘ DO NOT: Ask about multiple styles in one question

Stack Exchange aims to answer objectively answerable questions. If you’re asking about more than one style in one question, it opens up the potential for multiple correct answers. Keep it to one style per question so that your post fits the Stack Exchange format.

#### Other ways to improve your post

Make sure what you are asking about *is* a distinct style. Just because something uses the same shapes or colors it does not necessarily have the same style. Similarly, every small design decision does not have to correspond to a distinct *style*.

You should also avoid hot-linking to images on external sites. We cannot dependably rely on the longevity of external hosts, so please use the built-in image uploader.

You can help with our site’s organization by properly tagging it. Start off by tagging it as [style-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) and narrow it down by using  applicable descriptors such as [illustration](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustration), [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography), [line-art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-art). Please do not include superfluous tags such as [style](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style).

### Examples of well-formed style identification questions

- [What is the style of font called that is typically used in newspaper mastheads?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9155/8708)
- [Is there a name for logos with four letters in the quadrants of an X?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41961/8708)
- [How do you call tall, thick fonts, similar to Bebas?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19441/8708)