# What are the requirements for software identification-or-related questions?

Tags: discussion

I have come across a drawing with a certain style, and would like to know which software offer such capabilities. How should I construct my question to fit within this site's format?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply treat it as a [style-identification question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/what-are-the-requirements-for-style-identification-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1). It's difficult to tell without seeing it first but there may be more than one relevant software to accomplish the desired result.